# Apology letter to the company

Tags: job-search, job-description

My boss wants me to write an apology letter after they deposited my whole salary on wrong account while they have been paying me on a new account for the past two years,  and when the HR resolved the issue and ordered him to pay me he said l must first write an apology letter to the company. Why?

Plz help

Comment: Right, why? Ask that to your boss and HR.

Comment: Why would you apologize for their mistake?

Comment: `while they have been paying me on a new account for the past two years`..what do you mean, by the way?

Comment: Please edit your question and clarify the situation. We are having a hard time to understand what you're trying to ask.

Comment: @Paramone I'll be little more straight: Apologies, I clearly do not understand. :)

Comment: @ThemanOfhisOwnMind: Which is it? You provided correct account and they used wrong one? Or you changed account and forgot to communicate this to the company? Or you provided wrong account in the first place?

Comment: Please clarify: did you actually get paid into your own account?was the money deposited by your boss into their internall old account and just laying there dormant while they paid you from other sources? Did you have any involvement in chosing / naming what account your money was paid from and into? Did the company tell you why the expect you to apologize?

Comment: HR already ordered your boss to pay, though, right? So why's he attaching strings to this when he was already ordered to pay?

Answer (score 11):

Get legal advice immediately !

If you have not been paid (how did you survive without income) and now you're taking ownership of that "mistake" you might never see a dime or less than agreed to !

This smells fishy at best and you might be scammed here.

Your boss made a mistake.

Asking for your apology requires a reason, you being at fault, having made a mistake that they should clearly explain to you what it was.

Comment: He was paid, just into a different account. Towards beginning they sent money to the wrong account

Comment: @Twyxz but was it OP's account? Why is that a problem unless it was closed (in which case the transfer would have been denied,noc)?Did OP tell them the wrong account number or was it their mistake?

Answer (score 0):

They're making you write an apology for their mistake, so that you can get paid?

Just apologise and look for a new job. Don't cause any problems with it, get paid, get out.

Comment: Wouldn't this make it easier for the employer to withhold pay in some situations/countries? (obviously it depends what is written in the apology)